# Power BI Query Editor - Filter dates in Dataset based on external input (Excel)

Tags: sql, date, filter, powerbi, powerquery

I have a large dataset, with a *Date* column which goes into past dates and future dates.
I have an Excel table with a specific date (e.g. 01/05/2022). I want to filter out the rows which are in the past vs the input given (01/05/2022) by Excel. In the Power BI Query Editor.

I have only found a way on how to filter by current's date...

Thank you very much,

Comment: Read the table with the date into your query. Then you can refer to it

Answer (score 0):

In Excel, name the input date's cell (Range), such as 'ThruDate' (No spaces, special characters, etc).
From the Data Menu, use 'From Table/Range' to send it into PQ Editor.

In PQ Editor ThruDate query, change Column1 Type to DATE, and Rename the Column 'Date'

In your dataset query, manually filter the date column.

Here's the trick! Edit the code that that step created in the Formula Bar or Advanced Editor.

Replace #date(2022, 1, 5) with ThruDate[Date]{0}

Now, each time you change the Input Date in Range("ThruDate") and Refresh, you'll see only the dates after the input date.